# jQuery dropmenu button affects the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

The following code that I prepared with jQuery affects the drop menu elements on the whole page. What is the solution to the problem?

```
$(".dropmenuac").on("click",function(){
        $(".dropmenulist").css("opacity","1");
        $(".dropmenulist").css("pointer-events","auto");
        $(".dropmenuac").css("display","none");
        $(".dropmenukapa").css("display","block");
    });

    $(".dropmenukapa").on("click",function(){
        $(".dropmenulist").css("opacity","0");
        $(".dropmenulist").css("pointer-events","none");
        $(".dropmenuac").css("display","block");
        $(".dropmenukapa").css("display","none");
    });
```

You can see the detail in the picture.
http://forumuni.com/drop.png

I made a dropdown menu for the shares on my PHP page, but the jQuery code affected the whole page.

Comment: Rather than all that inline styling you can probably just toggle a single class on the outer element.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're targeting all of them at once. You need [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to solve this by binding function for each element separately.

Like this:

```
$(".dropmenuac").each(function() {
  $(this).on("click",function(){
    $(".dropmenulist").css("opacity","1");
    $(".dropmenulist").css("pointer-events","auto");
    $(".dropmenuac").css("display","none");
    $(".dropmenukapa").css("display","block");
  });
});

$(".dropmenukapa").each(function() {
  $(this).on("click",function(){
    $(".dropmenulist").css("opacity","0");
    $(".dropmenulist").css("pointer-events","none");
    $(".dropmenuac").css("display","block");
    $(".dropmenukapa").css("display","none");
  });
});
```